# jsreport templates storage is not persistent on azure docker

Tags: docker, azure

I deployed jsreport on **Azure Web App with Docker**. It was deployed successfully but after one day my templates were disappeared. I imported the templates again and after few hours templates were again disappeared. I then configured the azure file storage credentials on **Application Settings** of docker app. after restart templates were deleted, I assumed that new storage is attached so previous data is removed. I again imported the templates but after one day again templates disappeared.

can anyone please suggest whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For one instance we can use jsreport without service bus. Just removed these environment variables and it worked fine.

extensions_fsStore_sync_provider=azure-sb
extensions_fsStoreAzureSbSync_connectionString=xxx